# Why does Python3 interpreter raise UnicodeEncodeError only when it's executed through fcron?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, io, cron

Given the simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

b = 'строка'.encode()
print(b.decode('utf-8'))
```

If I run it directly as `python3 script.py` or `/full/path/to/script.py` or indirectly through crontab (e.g. `0 0 * * * /full/path/to/script.py`) then it's executed normally (without errors). But when it's executed through **fcrontab** for the same $USER (with same job `0 0 * * * /full/path/to/script.py`) then Python 3.5.2 raise exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/full/path/to/script.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(b.decode('utf-8')) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can it be possible? Why does Python try decode bytes as 'ascii' instead of 'utf-8'?

Comment: See here https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: Oh, it's really problem with only `print` function because of locale that's set for fcron (in my case fcron has locales 'POSIX' instead of *.UTF-8)... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Voina solution was found.

The problem is because of locale environment of fcron: it replaces default locale with POSIX, so Python cannot write unicode to stdout/stderr.[This thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.fcron.general/173) describes solution for this problem: it's only necessary add line `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` (or other locale settings) at the top of `fcrontab -e` and now script executes without I/O errors.

Example of `fcrontab -l`:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
0 0 * * * /full/path/to/script.py
```